# Return method in CoffeeScript

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

How to I do this in CoffeeScript:

```
window.onload = function() {
  test.init();
};

var test = (function() {
  var num = 1;

  var pub = function() {
    document.body.innerHTML = num;
  };

  return {
    init: function() {
      pub();
    }
  }

}());
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SsL9y/)

Comment: You can use JavaScript in your CoffeeScript files.

Comment: Of course I can. I wouldn't have asked what the CoffeeScript way to do this is, if I wanted to use JS in my .coffee files...

Comment: Just making sure you're aware of all the options :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This translates quite one-by-one:

```
window.onload = ->
  test.init()

test = do ->
  num = 1
  pub = ->
    document.body.innerHTML = num;

  init: ->
    pub()
```

([compile](http://coffeescript.org/#try%3awindow.onload%20%3D%20-%3E%0A%20%20test.init%28%29%0A%0Atest%20%3D%20do%20-%3E%0A%20%20num%20%3D%201%0A%20%20pub%20%3D%20-%3E%0A%20%20%20%20document.body.innerHTML%20%3D%20num%3B%0A%0A%20%20init%3A%20-%3E%0A%20%20%20%20pub%28%29))

However, you might shorten it (and the js similarly) to just

```
test = do ->
  num = 1
  init: ->
    document.body.innerHTML = num;
window.onload = test.init
```

([compile](http://coffeescript.org/#try%3atest%20%3D%20do%20-%3E%0A%20%20num%20%3D%201%0A%20%20init%3A%20-%3E%0A%20%20%20%20document.body.innerHTML%20%3D%20num%3B%0Awindow.onload%20%3D%20test.init))

Optionally, you can insert empty parenthesis (no parameters) before every `->`.

Comment: Thanks, this works fine. I'm aware I can shorten the code, but this was just a preview, I'll have a lot more functionality there, so this is my base structure I wanted to create.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like this should do the trick:

```
window.onload = -> test.init()

test = do ->
  num = 1
  pub = -> document.body.innerHTML = num
  init: -> pub()
```

Or this, if you explicitly don't want the functions to return anything:

```
window.onload = ->
  test.init()
  return

test = do ->
  num = 1
  pub = ->
    document.body.innerHTML = num
    return
  init: ->
    pub()
    return
```

Comment: @Bergi was faster on this, before you edited your post. I'll give you an upvote, because your previous solution worked fine as well. Cheers.

Comment: @AlexanderPetkov: Yea, I wasn't aware of the `do` keyword, that's a little better than those extra parens I had. Other than that, our solutions seem identical. Thanks for the recognition.

Answer (score 0):

[js-2-coffee](http://js2coffee.org/) is a really handy website for this kind of thing in the future

It gives the following coffeescript when you paste in your javascript

```
window.onload = ->
  test.init()
  return

test = (->
  num = 1
  pub = ->
    document.body.innerHTML = num
    return

  init: ->
    pub()
    return
())
```

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't aware of this website, it will come handy indeed. Still didn't give me the best solution, using the `do` keyword, but it is close at least.